# Литература для сдачи экзамена на oracle database sql expert

Tags: sql, книги

Добрые люди, вот такой вопрос я программировал на c/c#. Теперь срочно нужно пройти тест на оракл, причем это не прихоть а необходимость. Нужно получить сертификат *Oracle database sql expert*. Знаний в по SQL нуль. С чего начать? Сроки короткие всего 2 месяца до здачи экзамена. Какие книги и литературу посоветуете, желательно, на русском?

Answer (score 3):

Если нужна практика по SQL, то [сюда](http://www.sql-ex.ru/).